# Fetching data by GraphQL

Tags: mysql, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm using GraphQL with graphql-sequelize and mysql db. I need to fetch all products, whose users have status = true. As I understand, this query is wrong:

```
{
  products {
    name
    users(where: { status: true }) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And this query is correct:

```
{
  products(where: { users: { status: true } }) {
    name
    users {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Is it true? But graphql-sequelize does not understand nested object agrument:

```
where: { users: { status: true } }
```

Is there any workaround? How should I use sequelize here in correct way?

Comment: *" in this way I'll fetch all products and attach users to them, who has status = true. I mean, in this way condition relates to the second level of graph."* Well select N+1 problems pretty much always exists in GraphQL if that is your point unless the client resolves it.. Not sure if that library can optimize those cases automatic..

Comment: Ok, If I query like "where: { users: { status: true } }" graphql-sequelize throws an error "Unknown vaue { status: true } because it waiting for scalar value and can't work with nested arguments

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't want to use where as query variable. I just want to use nested argument. If I use i.e. "where: { name: "John" }" - everything is ok, but If want to use it for assosiated item  like "where: { users: { name: "John" } }" - I mean, nested argument, it fails

Comment: *"I don't want to use where as query variable. I just want to use nested argument"* well i think i need coffee really bad it seams... ` graphql-sequelize` has extended the GraphQL specs with a `where:` filter not sure how it works... But like i said before the GraphQL spec valid query would be `{
  products {
    name
    users(status: true) {
      id
    }
  }
}`  which i assume means the same as your first `graphql-sequelize` query..  Well like i said before not sure if that library can optimize those cases automatic to avoid select N+1 problems

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. These  two queries above return two different results: 1. returns ALL products, and then, attach only users with status: true. 2. returns ONLY that products, who has user with status: true

Comment: if that is the case `graphql-sequelize` does supports condition push down and does gives unexpected results because of that... As in the GraphQL specs it's not allowed to use inner type in the outer type more or less the same way as (My)SQL corelated subqueries..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to limit the query to products where the users meet a certain condition, we need an inner join (i.e. an `include` with `require` set to `true`). `graphql-sequelize` doesn't utilize `include` at all under the hood, so you won't get this functionality out of the box. However, you should be able to implement it yourself. Something like:

```
resolver(ProductModel, {
  // other options
  before: (findOptions, args, context) => {
    if (args.users) {
      findOptions.include = [{
        model: UserModel,
        required: true,
        where: args.users,
      }]
    }
    return findOptions;
  },
}
```